# basic ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How do we show the ring homomorphism for

$\phi :\mathbb F_p(\alpha) \rightarrow\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ which is defined as $ \phi(\alpha)=\alpha +1$.

This is a very basic fact but I am unable to prove it by the definition of ring homomorphism. Same thing happens for ring homomorphism over $\phi :K[x] \rightarrow K[X]$ defined as $\phi (X)=X+1$. I have studied this earlier and assumed it as trivial but never tried to see the proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You meant defined for $\;\alpha\;$ as you show and then generalized to $\;\Bbb F_p(\alpha)\;$ by the usual way. What is $\;\alpha\;$ , though?

Comment: Here $\mathbb F_p (alpha)$ is the splitting field field of $x^p-x+a$ and $\alpha $ is a root of that polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so $\;\Bbb F_p(\alpha)\;$ is a finite, and thus algebraic, extension of $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ , but also

$$\alpha^p-\alpha+a=0\implies (\alpha+1)^p-(\alpha+1)+a=\alpha^p+1-\alpha-a+a=0$$

so both $\;\alpha,\,\alpha+1\;$ are roots of the same polynomial irreducible polynomial over $\;\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ and thus there always exist a $\;\Bbb F_p$-automorphism of $\;\Bbb F_p(\alpha)\;$ mapping one of these roots to the  other one, which is given by your map.

For example:

$$\phi(a_{p-1}\alpha^{p-1}+\ldots+a_1\alpha+a_0)=0\iff$$

$$0=a_{p-1}(\alpha+1)^{p-1}+\ldots+a_1(\alpha+1)+a_0=$$

$$=a_{p-1}\alpha^{p-1}+\ldots+a_1\alpha+\left(a_0+a_{p-1}+\ldots+a_1\right)\stackrel{\text{by lin. indep.}}\implies$$

$$\implies\begin{cases}a_{p-1}=0\\a_p=0\\...\\a_1=0\\a_0+\ldots+a_{p-1}=0\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies a_i=0\;\;\;\forall\;1=0,1,2,...,p-1$$

and $\;\phi\;$ is injective then. And this is enough, because $\;\phi\;$ is in particular a linear operator on a finite dimensional linear , so it is injective$\;\iff\;$ it is surjective $\;\iff\;$ it is bijective.

By the way, you could as well take $\;\alpha+x\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb F_p\;$ . Any of these is a root of the above polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Let us start with your second question.

Let $K$ be a field, and $K[x]$ be the polynomial rings. Let $B$ be a commutative ring with unity containing $K$ as a subring, and let $\beta \in B$. Then there is a unique ring homomorphism
$$
v_{\beta} : K[x] \to B
$$
which satisfies
$$\begin{cases}
v_{\beta}: &a \mapsto a &\text{for $a \in K$},\\
           & x \mapsto \beta.\\
\end{cases}$$
This is just *evaluation of a polynomial for $x = \beta$*. The statement, which allows several generalizations, can be described as the universal property of polynomial rings.

---

As to your first question (which originally was missing the part on the polynomial of which $\alpha$ is a root), let $f = x^{p} - x - b$, for some $b \ne 0$. Note that $b$ has additive period $p$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, apply the Frobenius morphism $z \mapsto z^{p}$, then $\alpha^{p}$ is also a root, as
$$
0 = f(\alpha)^{p} = (\alpha^{p} - \alpha - b)^{p} 
= (\alpha^{p})^{p} - (\alpha^{p}) - b = f(\alpha^{p}).
$$
And clearly $\alpha^{p} = \alpha + b$. Since $\mathbb F_p(\alpha) = \mathbb F_p(\alpha+b)$, you have found that the Frobenius map induces a ring isomorphism $\sigma$ on $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ which fixes $\mathbb F_p$ elementwise and maps $\alpha$ to $\alpha + b$.

Now note that $\sigma^{i}(\alpha) = \alpha + i b$. Since $b \ne 0$ has additive period $p$, you can choose $i_{0}$ so that $i_{0} b = 1$, and thus
$$
\sigma^{i_{0}} (\alpha) = \alpha + 1.
$$